# Multiple frames, loading multiple fragments, can't control backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity with two containers for fragments, container_left and container_right.

At the beginning of navigation, a list fragment is in container_left, and the fragment that loads into container_right is a screen with several buttons.

When someone selects a button in the fragment in container_right, that fragment replaces the one in container_left, and a new fragment is loaded into container_right. At this point, I have saved this transaction to the backstack. If the back button is pressed at this point, the original list loads into container_left, and the button fragment loads into container_right. But if the person selects another button (now in the left hand frame), it adds a different fragment to the right hand container. I don't want to add the new transaction to the backstack, as I don't want to save the transactions where only fragment_container_right changes. I want the back button to only change the positions of the fragments.

The problem is, the transaction in the backstack is looking for the original fragment that was removed in the right frame, and since that has changed, it doesn't remove the new fragment, so the button fragment appears ON TOP of the new fragment in container_right.

I have been messing with this for a while, but I can't figure this one out.

How can I set this up so that when it pops the stack, any fragments currently in container_right are removed, even if they aren't the ones that were there when the transaction was committed?

here is a sample of what I have so far for loading the frames.  As you can see, I check to see if the control buttons are in the left frame before committing, so it isn't loading a new instance on every button push, and I do the same for each fragment loading into container_right, so I'm not creating a new fragment if someone hits the button for a fragment that is already loaded. The only issue left is the backstack transaction.

```
if (!(controlsInLeftFrame)) {
           getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                   replace(R.id.fragment_container_right, fragAD).
                   replace(R.id.fragment_container_left, fragRECB).addToBackStack(null).commit();
       } else if (!(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container_right) instanceof FragAttributeDescription)){
           getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                   replace(R.id.fragment_container_right, fragAD).commit();
       }
    }

    if (message.equals("Movement")) {

        FragRaceEditorMovement fragRM = new FragRaceEditorMovement();
        fragRM.setArguments(bundle);

        if (!(controlsInLeftFrame)) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                    replace(R.id.fragment_container_right, fragRM).
                    replace(R.id.fragment_container_left, fragRECB).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        } else if (!(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container_right) instanceof FragRaceEditorMovement)){
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                    replace(R.id.fragment_container_right, fragRM).commit();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

overriding onBackPressed() worked.  I had tried it once before, but realized that I had forgotten to put super.onBackPressed() AFTER removing the right hand fragment.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container_right)).commit();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

this appears to have solved the problem adequately